# Unpack and re-join fixed width text

Tags: python, bash, awk, sed, scripting

I have fixed width delimited file as follows

```
aaaaa003aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbb002aaaaaaaaaa
ccccc004cccccccccccccccccccc
```

I need to get it in the form

```
aaaaa003aaaaa
aaaaa003aaaaa
aaaaa003aaaaa
bbbbb002aaaaa
bbbbb002aaaaa
ccccc004ccccc
ccccc004ccccc
ccccc004ccccc
ccccc004ccccc
```

My current script is in efficient for 11 million lines. How can I optimise this?

```
#!/bin/sh
# My first Script
echo "Unbulking"
IN=$1
OUT=$2
while IFS= read -r line;do
    HEAD=${line:0:8}
    BODY=$(echo $line | sed -r ’s/.{8}//‘)
    BODYVAR=$(echo $BODY |fold -w 5)
    for i in ${BODYVAR}
    do
        echo $HEAD$i >> $OUT
    done
done < $IN
echo "Completed"
```

My logic needs to be along the lines:

```
#take the first 8 characters of a line and assign to a str1
#take the last 3 characters of str1 and cast to a intger and assign to num1
#multiply num1 by 5 and assign to num2
#return the substring from char 8 to num2 and assign to str2
#cut str2 into chunks of 5 and assign to an array arr1
#concatenate str1 with each element of arr1
#return the arr1 as a set of new lines
#repeat for everyline in the file
```

Comment: Welcome to forums, so you mean you need to split all characters after 3 digits into 4-4 groups, could you please clarify on logic of getting the sample expected output in your question.

Comment: what happens if a line is `aaaaa003xyz` or `aaaaa003x(*16)`?

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to manipulate text with a shell loop as the extreme slowness you've already noticed is just one of the issues you'll have, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for that issue and see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes, https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor, and [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization) for some of the other issues in the script you posted.

Using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    head = substr($0,1,8)
    tail = substr($0,9)
    while ( tail != "" ) {
        print head substr(tail,1,5)
        tail = substr(tail,6)
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
aaaaa003aaaaa
aaaaa003aaaaa
aaaaa003aaaaa
bbbbb002aaaaa
bbbbb002aaaaa
ccccc004ccccc
ccccc004ccccc
ccccc004ccccc
ccccc004ccccc
```

Answer (score 1):

Your entire script can be translated into gawk like this:

```
gawk 'BEGIN {
  FPAT=".{1,5}"
  OFS=""
}
{ head = substr($0,1,8)
  $0 = substr($0,9)
  for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
    print head, $i
}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

One for GNU awk. It `split` the record by string of digits and `prints` `$1` digits and $2 in 5 char parts:

```
$ gawk '{
    split($0,a,/[0-9]+/,seps)
    while(length(a[2])) {
        print a[1] seps[1] substr(a[2],1,5)
        a[2]=substr(a[2],6) 
    }
}' file
```

Output:

```
aaaaa003aaaaa
aaaaa003aaaaa
aaaaa003aaaaa
bbbbb002aaaaa
bbbbb002aaaaa
ccccc004ccccc
ccccc004ccccc
ccccc004ccccc
ccccc004ccccc
```

Gnu awk only as it uses the fourth parameter of `split()`, *seps*.

**Update:** Another version:

```
$ awk '{
    while(p=substr($0,9,5)) {
        print substr($0,1,8) p
        $0=substr($0,1,8) substr($0,14)
    }
}'
```

Comment: compact, but doesn't follow OP's requirement, OP didn't say the first part `aaaaa` doesn't contain `0-9`

Comment: Updated with another version (still didn't read the reqs, though :).